# Integral of a square root of a complex number

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I found the following exercise:

Compute $$\int_C \sqrt{z} dz$$
Where $C= \{e^{it}, t \in [0, \pi] \}$ (upper half of a circle) and $\sqrt{z}$ is a principal branch of square root function.

I study on my own and need some help. How to compute this integral? I know that $\sqrt{z} = e^{\frac12 log(z)} $ for the principal branch and what next? Or maybe it's not a proper attempt? I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you mean to write $t \in [0,\pi]?$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You also know that $z=e^{it}$, so you can use substitution to get the correct answer.

Comment: So I got $\int_0^\pi e^{\frac12 log(e^{it})} dt = \int_0^\pi e^{\frac12 it} dt = \frac{2}{i} (e^{\frac12 i \pi} -1)$. Is it correct? Would you be so kind and check it?

Comment: Of course it's wrong, I forgot what happens to dz when substituting z. I'm going to write more proper answer in a minute.

Comment: Ok, so I got $\int_0^\pi e^{\frac12 log(e^{it})} i e^{it} dt = \frac23 (e^{3/2\pi i} -1)$. It's the first complex integral I've ever computed, so I hope it's correct.